# How to store the output of @time to a variable?

Tags: julia

Is possible to store the time displayed with `@time` in a variable ?

For example the following code

```
for i in 1:10
    @time my_function(i)
end
```

displays the wall time of my function `my_function`, but I would like to store the number of milliseconds in an array instead, in order to display it in a plot showing the evolution of the execution time regarding the parameter `i`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest is to use `@elapsed`, e.g.:

```
julia> [@elapsed rand(5^i) for i in 1:10]
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 3.96e-6
 4.64e-7
 7.55e-7
 3.909e-6
 4.43e-6
 1.5367e-5
 7.0791e-5
 0.000402877
 0.001831287
 0.071062595
```

and if you use BenchmarkTools.jl then there is also `@belapsed` macro there for more accurate benchmarking than `@elapsed`.

EDIT:

- `@time`: is **printing** the time it took to execute, the number of allocations, and the total number of bytes its execution caused to be allocated, before **returning the value of the expression**. Any time spent garbage collecting (gc) or compiling is shown as a percentage.
- `@elapsed`: **discarding the resulting value**, instead **returning** the number of seconds it took to execute as a floating-point number

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Is there a difference between `@time` and `@elapsed` ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to highlight the differences between them.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add another example using `@elapsed begin` to show how it can be used to time multiple lines of code:

```
dt = @elapsed begin
  x = 1
  y = 2
  z = x^2 + y
  print(z)
end
```

Additionally, if this is not for benchmarking code and you just want time as an output you can alternatively use `time()`:

```
t = time()

x = 1
y = 2
z = x^2 + y
print(z)

dt = time() - t
```